# selenium popup save file issue using python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a html with selenium. After clicking the last link, pop up comes which says as save a file.
using selenium I am recording all the events and then generating the selenium RC script.
I want to know that  how to get the pop up file from code using python?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of saving a file, you can get around the popup box by configuring the options of your browser profile. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099250/python-webcrawler-downloading-files/12099438) answer for an explanation using Firefox. General idea is that you need to tell Firefox itself to not prompt when saving files of certain types. Note that this will result in the file being saved somewhere, but you can also control where it goes in case you want to delete the file (or handle it separately in Python).

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver cannot communicate with the browser modal popup.
But this can be done, check out the below link for your answer

http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/